# Weird C-shell return code for evaluating 1-1

Tags: shell, csh

I am doing this in csh

```
set it = `expr 1 - 1`
echo $?
```

It sets `it` to 0, but the error code returned is 1. Why is the error code not 0 if the expression evaluated correctly and the answer was set correctly?

On the other hand if I had

```
set it = `expr 2 - 1`
echo $?
```

then the error code is 0. What is the problem with evaluating 1-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `expr` is weird. The same happens with any expression that evaluates to zero.

Quoting the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?expr):

> Exit status is 0 if EXPRESSION is neither null nor 0, 1   if  EXPRESSION
>   is  null   or  0,  2 if EXPRESSION is syntactically invalid, and 3 if
>   an error occurred.

Shell arithmetic is preferable.

```
@ it = 1 - 1
echo $? : $it
0 : 0
```